# Batch: Trying to get a command to execute at a specific amount of seconds

Tags: time, batch-file, command, timed

This works for hours, running in a loop as soon as it hits 13 hours it executes.

```
@ECHO OFF

:time
echo %time%
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a IN ("$0%time:~0,2%") DO SET /a HH=%%b
IF %HH% equ 13 goto success
goto time

:success
echo success finally
pause
goto time
```

but if I run this for seconds in a loop for it to execute at 13 seconds it just keeps running in a loop and doesn't execute the command.

```
@ECHO OFF

:time
echo %time%
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a IN ("$0%time:~5,2%") DO SET /a SS=%%b
IF %SS% equ 13 goto success
goto time

:success
echo success finally
pause
goto time
```

This Doesn't Work either

```
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a IN ("$0%time:~6,2%") DO SET /a SS=%%b
```

I need this to execute at any specified amount of seconds. So that instead of for instance executing at 13:00:00.00. I can get it to execute at 13:00:13.00 or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to be a 6 not a 5 for the offset.

```
%time:~6,2%
```

It does not have to be complex. This works, but unless you provide more details as to what you are trying to accomplish we cannot provide the best help.

```
:time
echo %time%
IF %time:~6,2% equ 13 goto success
goto time
```

Note that using the `time` environment variable is user locale specific.

Use something like for no locale format time.

```
wmic path win32_operatingsystem get LocalDateTime
```

Comment: changing the 5 to a 6 still doesn't make the command execute.

Comment: ok on the seconds it is basically picking and choosing wen to stop it seems even with he 0's edit it seems to just fly by the 0's if it is set for those and ends up saying missing operation. I find that i may have an error somewhere now.